# Execution failed for task Program type already present?

Tags: android, windows, sdk, android-support-library

I have this error while build Application

```
Error:Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$ViewElevationComparator
```

any idea about this error ?

Comment: I'm not sure but re-check your dependencies. maybe one of them's got support dependency. if you found the one then you can `exclude group: 'com.android.support'` from that dependency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just stumbled upon this error on the latest Android Studio 3.2 Canary 4 with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha04'`. It was fixed as soon as I updated the support libraries to 27.1.0